# Finding the length of a piece of string using Lagrange multipliers

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

A string of fixed length L is to be cut into three pieces of length
x, y and z. The string of length x is to be shaped into a circle, the string
of length y is to be shaped into a square and the string of length z is to be
shaped into triangle with angles π/2, π/4, π/4.
How do I use Lagrange multipliers to find the values of x, y and z where local minima or maxima may occur.

Comment: What do you want to maximize (minimize) ?

Comment: You know the perimeter of each object. You can compute the corresponding areas then the total area. Take into account the constraint $x+y+z=L$.

Comment: To make lif easier, set $L=1$.

Answer (score 0):

to maximize area, it should be clear that one shape has a higher area / perimeter ratio than multiple shapes.  Furthermore, the circle more efficient than the other shapes.  So all of the string in one circle maximizes area.

to minimize area.

$2\pi r = x\\
r = \frac {x}{2\pi}$

Area of a circle $= \pi r^2 =  \frac{x^2}{4\pi}$

sqrare:

$4s = y\\
s = \frac {y}{4}$

Area $= s^2 = \frac {y^2}{16}$

Triangle

$(2 + \sqrt 2)s = z\\
s = \frac {z}{2 + \sqrt 2}$

Area $= \frac 12 s^2 = \frac {z^2}{12+8\sqrt{2}}$

minimize: $\frac {1}{4\pi} x^2 + \frac {1}{16} y^2 + \frac 1{12+8\sqrt2} z^2$

constrained by $x+y+z = L$

$f(x,y,z,\lambda) = \frac {1}{4\pi} x^2 + \frac {1}{16} y^2 + \frac 1{12+8\sqrt2} z^2 - \lambda (x+y+z-L)$

$\frac {\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac {2}{4\pi} x  - \lambda = 0\\
\frac {\partial f}{\partial y} =  \frac {2}{16} y  - \lambda = 0\\
\frac {\partial f}{\partial z} = \frac 2{12+8\sqrt2} y  - \lambda = 0\\
\frac {\partial f}{\partial \lambda} = x+y+z - L = 0$

And this is a system of linear equations which you learned how to solve in basic algebra.